# Add JPanel Class to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I would like to add a JPanel Class, when I click on a button in the first JPanel Class

```
class LaunchForm extends JPanel {
    public static JButton btnSettings;
    private ButtonActionHandler buttonActionHandler;

    LaunchForm() {
        buttonActionHandler = new ButtonActionHandler();
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        btnSettings = new JButton();
        createButton(btnSettings, 385, 190, 191, 55, path_btnStartGame);
    }

    private void createButton(JButton button, int  x, int y, int width, int height, String filePath) {
        button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(LaunchForm.class.getResource(filePath)));
        button.setBackground(bgColor);
        button.setForeground(Color.white);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        button.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonActionHandler());
        add(button);
    }

    public class ButtonActionHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            add(new SettingsPanel());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my SettingsPanel which gets displayed correctly, when I launch the programm with this Panel.

```
class SettingsPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton btnBack;

    SettingsPanel() {
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        btnBack = new JButton();
        createButton(btnBack, 30, 30, 40, 40, path_btnLeftArrow);
    }

    private void createButton(JButton button, int  x, int y, int width, int height, String filePath) {
        button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(LaunchForm.class.getResource(filePath)));
        button.setBackground(bgColor);
        button.setForeground(Color.white);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        button.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        add(button);
    }
}
```

However, it somehow doesn't work. And I don't want to open a new window. I just want to "switch" the JPanel with the SettingsPanel.

So, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Better to 1) swap components, such as a blank JPanel for the one that you want to show 2) use CardLayout to help you do this, 3) avoid null layouts like the plague since they will harm you in the end (as yours is doing now)

Comment: Does this also work with having the other panel in another class?

Comment: That is an orthogonal issue and doesn't affect the overall solution